# $ionicPopup.alert() can't be turned off

Tags: ionic-framework

If a alert popup don't be closed manually，webpage-redirecting can not be turned off.So what's the problem?How to do can close the alert popup.

```
$ionicPopup.alert({title:"error",template:"error"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically close the popup using `close` function of the returned promise.

```
popup = $ionicPopup.alert({title:"error",template:"error"});

//then...

popup.close();
```

[Check the documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).